# Como Puedo hacer que un Jbutton haga un calculo con 2 valores que el usuario le ha representado en unos jtextLabels anteriormente?

Tags: java, jbutton, jlabel

Quiero hacer una intefaz para calcular el area de un triangulo equilátero ,
quiero que en JText Field Base el usuario pueda introducir un valor double que seria la base del triangulo y que en el JText Field Altura el usuario pueda introducir otro valor double que seria la altura del triangulo . Despues me gustaria que el jButton1 calcule el area de un triagulo equilatero (base*altura)/2 , me imprima el resultado en el jLabel areaResult y si es posible me imprima el procedimiento en el Jlabel proced. Si alguien me pudiera dar algunos consejos estaria muy agradecido , soy nuevo en esto de Java y solo he conseguido crear la interfaz y algunos botones.
Gracias de antemano.
aqui debajo esta el codigo que tengo escrito en NetBeans 12.0

````
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Bernat
 */
public class Triangulo extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Triangulo
     */
    public Triangulo() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    @Override
 public Image getIconImage() {
        Image retValue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("imagenes/logohp.png"));
        return retValue;}
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Base = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        Altura = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        proced = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        areaResult = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Nirmala UI", 0, 10)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.setText("SOLO TRIANGULOS EQUILATEROS(de momento)");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 20, -1, -1));

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);
        jTextField2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        jTextField2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jTextField2.setText("@bernsteinn");
        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jTextField2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, -1, -1));

        Base.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                BaseActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(Base, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 110, 110, -1));
        getContentPane().add(Altura, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(160, 140, 110, -1));

        jButton1.setText("CALCULAR");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 190, -1, -1));

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Yi Baiti", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel2.setText("Base");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 90, 50, 50));

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft Yi Baiti", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel3.setText("Altura");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(110, 130, 70, 30));

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Yu Gothic UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel4.setText("AREA(Resultat)=");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 260, 180, 30));

        proced.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        proced.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        proced.setText("AREA(Procediment)=");
        getContentPane().add(proced, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 240, -1, -1));

        areaResult.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        getContentPane().add(areaResult, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(170, 270, 130, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 246, 100, 20));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondo-abstracto-degradado-negro-simple_1962-1556.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 400, 300));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    }                                           

    private void BaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        double base = new Double(Base.getText());
        double altura = new Double(Altura.getText());
       
        
       
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Triangulo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Triangulo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Triangulo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Triangulo.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Triangulo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField Altura;
    private javax.swing.JTextField Base;
    private javax.swing.JLabel areaResult;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel proced;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}```
````

Comment: Si alguien necesita algun otro dato que me lo pida . Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes declarar una Funcion que se encargue de obtener los datos de los textFild y operarlos para ello vas a necesitar que esa funcion tenga 3 variables de tipo double 2 paros los datos de base y altura y una para el total el cual debes regresar a un label del área, luego llamarla en el action de tu boton y ya, la funcion podría quedar así

```
    public void calcularArea(){
            double base,altura,total;
            //pasar datos de los textField a variables
            //el metodo Double.parseDouble es para convertir los datos de tipo string que recibe el textField en datos de tipo double
            //dentro del parentesis va el dato que queremos convertir
            altura=Double.parseDouble(nombreTextfilAltura.getText());
            base=Double.parseDouble(NombreTextFildBase.getText());
            //ahora vamos a realizar nuestro calculo 
            total=(base*altura)/2;
            //ahora pasamos el resultado de la operacion a el label, para eso debemos convertirlo a String pero peude hacerse en la misma linea de codigo
            //igual que en el anterior String.valueOf nos sirve para pasar el dato dentro de los parentesis a string
            LabelTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

y en tu action button solo tendrías que llamar a la funcion

```
 private void BaseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    calcularArea();
}
```

Si te fue de ayuda te podrías suscribir a mi canal, apenas lo estoy empezando pero planeo subir pequeños tutoriales de 1 o 2 minutos sobre estos pequeños problemas y dudas de desarrollo te dejo el link por si te interesa: [Canal de youtube: ShortCode](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaKO4eWBt0bHG-GBvhuGQJg?view_as=subscriber)

Answer (score 0):

Los consejos no sirven (sino ya fueran un negociazo) Pero ahí te va.
Te recomiendo ampliamente que antes de hacer la interfaz gráfica, hagas funcionar tu programa en consola de salida. Crea un método que reciba dos valores y retorne el resultado. Si logras hacer eso, ya podrías pasarte a la interfaz. No lo hagas al revés.

Un método que cálcule una suma podría ser así:

```
    double sumarDosnumeros(double numa,double numb){
    double resultado = numa + numb ;
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias a los 2.